# Rails 3 Development Asset Pipeline Directs to Public Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, asset-pipeline

I just pulled down two new rails 3.2.6 projects that I have designated for some clean up. While attempting to make some UI changes I realized that even in development the asset pipeline was routing towards the public/assets folder.

After making some changes to the scss, I ran `rake assets:clean` followed by `rake assets:precompile`. Both ran without error and I restarted my localhost, and the styling was broken.

I've walked through the rails asset pipeline guide, as well as some other documentation that hasn't really provided the answer I need.

I attempted adding `config.serve_static_assets = false`to the `development.rb` file in the `config` folder, however this as well did not render any scss.

Can anyone explain what is happening, and the best method of resolution?

Thanks

Comment: Well, in development, you probably shouldn't precompile your assets. `rm -rf` the `public/assets` folder.

Comment: What was foreign to me was that they came precompiled, and directing to the `public/assets` folder. I initially `rm -rf` the `public/assets` folder, but that didn't solve the problem. It just removed all scss and js from the app. Then after trying research, I attempted to recompile the assets. I've now reverted the app to the state I brought it in at.

Comment: Just try one test by pre-compile the code in production mode and run the server for production mode. If you find everything okay means development modes sometimes create trouble in accessing assets files.

Answer (score 0):

Add below statement to development.rb to prevent loading of files from public/assets.

> config.serve_static_assets = false

Now restart the server, You will get better view.

To precomple the code in Test mode. -

Add this configuration to test.rb

> config.assets.compile = false
>
> config.serve_static_assets = true

Comment: Should have added to the description, I attempted this as well yesterday. Just tried and it didn't render any scss. I'm editing my question now to display that this was attempted. Thanks!